# Change the source of a video dynamically with IE using Video.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, video.js

Is it possible to change the source of a video dynamically with IE using Video.js?

This is the code I'm using. It works perfectly with Firefox and Chrome. But with IE it works only once, if I click on another video, I get "The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed of because the format is not supported."

I tested all the previous answers of questions similar to this one in Stackoverflow, but I still get the same error.

Html:

```
<video id='div_video' class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload='none' width='590' height='387'>
    <source src='' type="video/mp4">
    <source src='' type="video/webm">
</video>

<ul class="sbs_index">
    <li class='open_video' data-video='one'> One (1:08) </li>
    <li class='open_video' data-video='two'> Two (0:43) </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.open_video').on("click", function() {
            var video_src = $(this).data("video");
            var vid_obj;
            videojs("div_video").ready(function(){
                vid_obj = this;
                vid_obj.pause();
                vid_obj.src([
                    { type: "video/mp4", src: video_src + ".mp4" },
                    { type: "video/webm", src: video_src + ".webm" }
                ]);
                vid_obj.load();
                vid_obj.play();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the video load fine when you load it inline?

Comment: @rachel Yes it does.

Comment: Have you tried $(window).load(function() { to load the script?